# How to delete or remove a specific line from a text file

Tags: java

I was trying to delete a line from a file. I've search on the internet. And i made a method. Here is it.

```
public void removeLine(BufferedReader br , File f,  String Line) throws IOException{
    File temp = new File("temp.txt");
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(temp));
    String removeID = Line;
    String currentLine;
    while((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null){
        String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
        if(trimmedLine.equals(removeID)){
            currentLine = "";
        }
        bw.write(currentLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));

    }
    temp.renameTo(f);
    bw.close();
    br.close();
}
```

I don't know what is wrong with this method. Could you help me?

Here is where i use this method

```
delete.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {


        BufferedReader br = null;
    try{
    String enterID2 =  enterID1.getText().trim();
        File books = new File("books.txt");
         br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(books));
         removeLine(br , books, enterID2);
         System.out.println("done");

    }catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
               System.out.println("This is not a number");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    }
    });
```

Delete is a JButton. No error recieved.

Comment: Do you have an exception or nothing happens?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Just nothing. I put this method in a listener. And after this method works i write System.out.println("done"). And program writes done. But nothing happens with this method.

Comment: are you sure the method is being invoked ? Did you log any message to see if the method is being invoked ?

Comment: Have you check that `renameTo` returns `success`(true)? That might be the problem.

Comment: I' ve just add `System.out.println("method is invoked")` in the method. And its worked.

Comment: How can i do this. @DavideSpataro

Comment: Check the answer from @Gamles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
public static void removeLine(BufferedReader br , File f,  String Line) throws IOException{
    File temp = new File("temp.txt");
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(temp));
    String removeID = Line;
    String currentLine;
    while((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null){
        String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
        if(trimmedLine.equals(removeID)){
            currentLine = "";
        }
        bw.write(currentLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));

    }
    bw.close();
    br.close();
    boolean delete = f.delete();
    boolean b = temp.renameTo(f);
}
```

Comment: Wow. It's really worked. Thank you. But i don't understand the problem. Could you explain

Comment: I think that renameTo doesn't work because the file 'f' already exists. Also you were trying to modify the file without closing the BufferedReader that was using it, so maybe it was the reason it couldn't delete 'books.txt'.So it's better to close first the writer and reader

Comment: Yes. I understood. f is exists :). Thanks again.